# Take one replica offline from an availability group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups

I have 2 replicas running SQL Server 2016 Enterprise Edition in an AlwaysOn Availability Group.

One replica is primary and other replica is secondary and readable.

I have a business requirement that should allow one database replica to be taken offline and back online after a period of a few minutes by a custom developed APM monitor.

The database replica to be taken offline can be primary or secondary.

The database replica has to be take offline and online via transact SQL

When the database replica is offline it should not be possible for it to execute requests. All existing connections must be moved to the other database replica or fail, so that the client can reconnect using the IP listener to the other replica.

I can do a [suspend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/suspend-an-availability-database-sql-server) or a [planned manual failover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/perform-a-planned-manual-failover-of-an-availability-group-sql-server) but neither seems to support what I need.

The suspend & manual failover only works on secondary database replicas.

The suspend allows existing connections to execute requests.

The manual failover just switches the primary to secondary role and vice versa.

How do I do this ?

Comment: What happens if you just do a [`SHUTDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/shutdown-transact-sql) via TSQL for the node?

Comment: When you say replica - do you mean database replica or server replica?

Comment: @LowlyDBA quote from the suspend link " Existing connections on the readable secondary remain usable.  New connections to the suspended database on the readable secondary are not allowed until data movement is resumed."

Comment: @Sean database replica

Comment: @LowlyDBA shutdown is not an option as the SQL Server instance also hosts other databases which must remain online. Only the database in the AG must be taken offline on that instance.

Comment: @KelvinWayne may want to add to the question that you have it setup with a readable secondary as that configuration is noteworthy.

Comment: If you make the secondary non-readable before a failover, that should do it.

Comment: @Sean, so a combination of using manual failover to make the targeted instance secondary and then configure it no read-only access. And to enable it, i configure it to read_only.

What possible issues can this approach have ?

Comment: Set it as non-readable first, then do the failover to make it the secondary. If it's already the secondary, just make it non-readable. That should be enough. What issues? None, seems like the *issues* are what you want to cause.

Comment: @Sean, not looking for issues, but stability. 

I spoke to our DBA and he suggested we create a stored procedure for this to make it easy for the APM monitor to execute everything.


Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The database replica to be taken offline can be primary or secondary.

The database taken offline should **always** be the secondary.

> The database replica has to be take offline and online via transact SQL

That's possible.

> When the database replica is offline it should not be possible for it to execute requests. All existing connections must be moved to the other database replica or fail, so that the client can reconnect using the IP listener to the other replica.

Basically here's how it would go:

1. If the database replica that needs to be taken offline is a primary, check for the current secondary to be synchronized.
2. Set the database to be "taken down" as a non-readable secondary.
3. If the database replica was a primary, failover.
4. Do any other items you'd like here, such as removing it from the AG, etc.